# Xamarin Forms QueryParameter Being Ignored

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a shell app and I want to navigate from one page to another. I have followed the documentation and turotials step by step but for some reason the **QueryParameter** is being ignored(Since the **Init** method is not being called). Am I missing something?

First Page:

```
List<int> rowColumn = Methods.GetGridRowColumn((Frame)s);
HomeTab homeTab = dict[rowColumn[0]+""+rowColumn[1]];
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(homeTab);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CategoriesPage)}?homeTab={content}");
```

Page to navigate:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[QueryProperty(nameof(HomeTab), "homeTab")]
public partial class CategoriesPage : ContentPage
{
    private HomeTab homeTab;
    public string HomeTab
    {
        set 
        {
            string content = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
            homeTab = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HomeTab>(content);
            Init();
        }
    }

    public CategoriesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

}

Comment: I believe that QueryParameter is intended for use with basic value types and strings, not complex types that have been serialized

Comment: @Jason it was working fine. I do not remember that I edited it since then. But when I was testing the whole app this issue appeared.

Comment: @Jason I replaced the {content} by  a number and it worked. Could it be because I am sending a base64 string? as u know base64 string is too long.

Comment: as I said before, this is intended for basic value types and strings.  I think its safe to assume that base64 encoded data is probably a bad idea

Comment: Hi Sam.I think the `string content=Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);` is called. you can add breakpoints and try again.

Comment: And Is the page CategoriesPage open?

Comment: @打玻璃 I added a break point and it was not called. but when I send a simple parameter like string or int it works fine

Comment: Then `content` has a value? or it is null?

Comment: I think your `content` is null so there is no parameters to the `homeTab`@Sam